# UIView Animations Not Working Properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, swift, uiviewanimation

I'm currently experimenting with UIView animations in Swift. Im trying to resize a button from  (309, 452, 0, 0) to (400, 400, 150, 150). I have the code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.start.bounds = CGRectMake(400, 400, 150, 150)
        println(self.start.bounds);
    });

}
```

However, the button just suddenly appears from nothing (no transition) to 150x150 and transitions all the way to the top left corner (0,0). Even though the print statement prints out (309, 452, 150, 150) in the console, it does not to have that frame. I have also tried changing self.start.bounds to self.start.frame, but that doesn't do anything different.

Comment: Are you using auto layout for the button?

Comment: Nope, I removed all the auto layout constraints

Comment: If you are also changing the position then you should probably be using frame instead. I see in your questions that you've tried it but you should switch to using it that again. What is the frame before the animation (i.e. what is the model value before you change it)?

Comment: If I try using frame, it becomes (0,0,0,0). However, when I used bounds and printed out both the frame and bounds value, console outputted (400.0,400.0,150.0,150.0) for bounds and
(-75.0,-75.0,150.0,150.0) for frame

Comment: Don't change the bounds, pretty much ever for a button. Animate only the frame (or constraint constants).

Comment: When I try to change the frame to (400, 400, 150, 150), it just becomes (0, 0, 0, 0) though

Comment: Check in your storyboard's File Inspector, that you switched off Auto Layout for whole storyboard. If you don't do that, then your code won't have any result otherwise it should work with frame update.

Comment: I was sure I removed every auto layout constraint on the entire storyboard

Comment: Would running the app on a device with iOS 7.1 cause any problems if the iOS SDK is set to 8.0 in Xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is Auto Layout. I have started a new project with a ViewController and a start button. When I try to change the buttons frame in `viewDidLoad` with

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
            self.start.frame = CGRectMake(100, 500, 500, 50);
        }
```

The only thing that happens is the button text being fade in.
When I disable AutoLayout or SizeClasses for the View Controller, the button is animated correctly.

Comment: Omg, thanks so much! I spent ours with a similar problem and I would never guess Auto Layout was the problem.